# Как сохранить перевод строки при отображении текста из textarea?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

У меня есть форма, в которой содержится textarea. Введенный в нем текст отправляется на сервер, где сохраняется в базу данных. В базе данных все переводы строки в textarea сохраняются, но когда я возвращаю запись с базы данных на клиент, то на клиенте выводится текст без переноса строки. Как это исправить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/12831101/4711135

Answer (score 1):

Я решил эту проблему, просто обернув строку из textarea в тег

и прописав ей стиль "white-space: pre-line"

Answer (score 0):

Если хотите чтобы переносы работали без `<br>`, вставьте содержимое между тегов `<pre>` и `</pre>`.